# Change Menuitems when Sliding Tab

Tags: java, android, tabs

I followed this tutorial to build up a Sliding Tab application : 
http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html

Now my Question:
How can I change my Menu icons in my actionbar when I change to another Tab ?For example in Tab1 you can see a Search Icon and when you change to Tab2 this gets invisible but there comes a Add icon.

My code till now :

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    menu.add("menu_search").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_search_white_24dp).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    menu.add("menu_contact").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_add_white_24dp).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    return  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define menu in Fragment instead of Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ...
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_item_1:
        // handling menu item click
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Of course each Fragment will have its own menu with corresponding icons.

This is an example (menu_main.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_1"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/ic_menu_label"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_icon"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

Comment: How can I get my menu object there ?

Comment: @AhmetKazaman I added code for managing click on menu items and menu xml

Comment: Ok thanks that worked but its a kinda slow. Some tricks for performance ? it is appearing after 2-3 sec

Comment: @AhmetKazaman You mean slow in appearing while scrolling tabs? Unfortunately I think there's no trick for this. One more thing. Defining menu at Fragment level doesn't mean you cannot define it at Activity level too. Fragment menu just give a contribution but common menu items can be defined without problems at Activity level. You can refer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#ActionBar) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your help ^^. Im kinda thinking how Whatsapp can handle this ? its so fast in there